# Render user group in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-installation, users

I'm trying to install [Afanasy](http://cgru.info/afanasy/afanasy) on Ubuntu 20.04. Since Afanasy is an render farm manager, it (usually) creates a user named **render** while installing.

But I've found out that a user group **render** exists in Ubuntu 20.04, so Afanasy can't create **render** user and work properly.
So my question is why this **render** user group exists? Can I delete it without breaking my system?

Comment: Have you previously tried to install `Afanasy` or any other render-related tool? Find out what files use that group with `sudo find / -group render -ls`. Also read `man delgroup`

Comment: No, I use fresh Ubuntu 20.04 install in Virtualbox (I want to write bash script to automate Afanasy installation). I also tried fresh 18.04 and Afanasy works just fine.
Thanks for `sudo find ...` and `man delgroup` I'll check it out.

Comment: On my system, the render group owns (only) /dev/dri/render/renderD128.